# Best approach for placement of CTA, search and filter option with the nav tab

Tags: search, dashboard, filter

[image]

What would be the good place for placing the search and the filter options in the page title section with the CTA button?

What if the search are placed in the right side of the menu options, below the CTA button?

Comment: What is the primary use case of the CTA? What does it do?

Comment: To create a new Entity related to that page, for eg. creating a new question in the ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: how will you show the search results in this case of placing search above the tabs, considering the results will be more than one and each one falls under different tabs (one result in menu 1 and another in menu 3)?

Answer (score 1):

You're right about aligning the search and filter icons in the same line of tabs at the end, but the CTA should be placed after body content of that tab; considering that **CTA belongs to Menu 3**, because that's what you want your users to do - consume the content first and then take an action;  which basically goes in flow.

Currently, the CTA appears to be one main action of that entire section.

## Edit

Reading your comment - let the CTA be there, but consider placing the Search and Filter icon in vertical three dots (only if those are not too frequent actions users act on) to avoid clash of same icons within that proximity.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the CTA is the main action for the entire section, But i was thinking of the scenario when there are no tab menus, in that case what can be a good approach, placing them besides the CTA button. 

But in that case again, the two search are there within the same proximity.

Comment: They will be used mostly for filtering and searching the data. Example sceanario can be list of your contacts, where you can search a person and add a new contact as well. 

If its kept in the three dot, it will again take an extra click to do the search and filter activity.

Comment: I won't worry about an additional click if it is avoiding confusion & repetition. See the three dots in Chrome - chrome://history/